# Segfault with Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

My code is crashing with a segfault and I can't really figure out where the error is. I'm still learning the ways of pointers when it comes to passing them around as parameters and such. Here's the code that should matter to this. The segfault occurs when I run the `issueBook()` function.

IssuedBooks.h

```
#ifndef ISSUEDBOOKS_H
#define ISSUEDBOOKS_H

#include "ClientList.h"
#include "BookList.h"
#include <QMultiMap>

class IssuedBooks {
public:
    IssuedBooks() {}
    ~IssuedBooks();

    void issueBook(Client*, Book*);
    void returnBook(Client*, Book*);

    ClientList getClients() const;
    BookList getClientBooks(Client*) const;

private:
    QMultiMap<Client*, Book*> issuedBooks;
};

#endif
```

IssuedBooks.cpp

```
#include "IssuedBooks.h"
#include <qDebug>

IssuedBooks::~IssuedBooks(){
    qDeleteAll(issuedBooks);
    issuedBooks.clear();
}

void IssuedBooks::issueBook(Client* c, Book* b){
     if(!issuedBooks.contains(c, b)){
        issuedBooks.insert(c, b);
     }
}

void IssuedBooks::returnBook(Client* c, Book* b){
    if(issuedBooks.contains(c, b)){
        issuedBooks.remove(c, b);
    }
}

ClientList IssuedBooks::getClients() const{
    QMapIterator<Client*, Book*> itr(issuedBooks);
    ClientList clients;

    while(itr.hasNext()){
        itr.next();
        clients.addClient(itr.key());
    }

    return clients;
}

BookList IssuedBooks::getClientBooks(Client* c) const{
    QMapIterator<Client*, Book*> itr(issuedBooks);
    BookList books;

    while(itr.hasNext()){
        itr.next();
        if(itr.key() == c){
            books.addBook(itr.value());
        }
    }

    return books;
}
```

LibraryDriver.cpp

```
#include "ClientList.h"
#include "BookList.h"
#include "IssuedBooks.h"

#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>

QTextStream cout(stdout);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    BookList bookList;
    ClientList clientList;
    IssuedBooks issueList;

    Book* b = new Book("Nick Corin", "An awesome life.", 59.99);
    bookList.addBook(b);

    Client* c = new Client("Nick Corin", QDate::currentDate());
    clientList.addClient(c);

    issueList.issueBook(c, b);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried GDB to find out, why it crashes?

Comment: Your `issueBook` looks ok, so the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Someone commented asking about the app.exec() but now I can't find the comment? It actually did turn out to be that for some reason?

I added app.exe() to the end of my main function and all my problems have disappeared? Any idea why?

Comment: good catch! before actually doing anything with a `QApplication`, it needs to be `exe`cuted; otherwise, there won't be any Qt main loop and no properly set up Qt environment, which some of the things you do might try to access; accessing something that's not there will cause a segfault.

Comment: I never thought it would make such a difference, because the program was running just fine without it until I tried to issue books and got the segfault.

Really interesting! I wonder who commented and then removed it. You solved the problem whoever you were!

Answer (score 2):

Problems of this kind will be often encountered in your programming life, so here's a general solution:

1. You should try to find out where exactly the segfault is happening. I assume you're using GCC/ the GNU development toolchains. So the first thing you'd do is compile your code with the `-g` flag, which includes debugging symbols in the binary. If you're using an IDE, that's what's happening when you select "Debug" as build type. If you're calling `g++` yourself, add `-g` to the `g++` options.
2. load the program in gdb, the GNU DeBugger: `gdb --args yourprogram yourprogramarguments`.
3. run it: `(gdb) run<enter>`
4. wait for the segfault.
5. Use the `backtrace` command to figure out where the segfault happened.

There's plenty other useful gdb commands that let you `print` variables, or modify them in place. Often, you want to add `breakpoint`s; `help <commandname>` will print some help.

I wrote a little more comprehensive guide, tailored for GNU Radio developers, but it applies here too: [Using GDB to debug](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/TutorialsGDB)

Answer (score 0):

The most common error for beginner is to try use the object which has not been created and initialized. Because memory pointer in the variable points to the random address or null, memory access error (segfault) is created.

"In computing, a segmentation fault (often shortened to segfault) or access violation is a fault raised by hardware with memory protection, notifying an operating system (OS) about a memory access violation"

The issueBook() -function contains one strong candidate as a uninitialized variable.